# Alternatives to TBE buffer for denaturing polyacrylamide gel electrophoresis of DNA and RNA?

Tags: gel-electrophoresis

I just stumbled upon an article promoting 10 mM sodium borate as an alternative to the well-known TAE and TBE buffers for agarose gel electrophoresis of DNA ([Brody & Kern, 2004](http://www.biotechniques.com/multimedia/archive/00036/BTN_A_04362BM02_O_36180a.pdf)). They claim that sodium borate outperforms TBE and TAE at high-voltage conditions due to the significantly lower heat development.

I'm currently using TBE buffer and gels with 7M urea for my denaturing PAA gels, and I'm wondering if there are similar alternative conditions for those denaturing PAA gels of nucleic acids?

I couldn't find anything on using sodium borate for denaturing PAA gels, so I'm wondering if it should work the same as for the agarose gels or if it just isn't a good buffer for that kind of gel.

---

[Brody, J. R. & Kern, S. E. Sodium boric acid: a Tris-free, cooler conductive medium for DNA electrophoresis. BioTechniques 36, 214–216 (2004).](http://www.biotechniques.com/multimedia/archive/00036/BTN_A_04362BM02_O_36180a.pdf)

Comment: Not related to your question but what voltage are you running your gels? It seems as if your having all sorts of issues with over-heating.

Comment: 250V (results in ~30-35mA), I'm having no significant overheating problems, but if I could just run the gels faster at higher voltages it might be useful.

Comment: @bobthejoe PAGE and PAA gel electrophoresis are the same thing, if you mean a discontinuous gel like SDS-PAGE for proteins that doesn't exist for nucleic acids as far as I know.

Comment: For what it's worth, I use TAE with agarose and never exceed 90 V (~20 mA). Resolution is always better at lower temperature conditions, in this case, meaning lower voltages.

Comment: @leonardo, I've always heard that its the other way. CE  is run at a high temperature to improve resolution. This is worth a question...

Comment: This is a good question. I'll look around for a reference later, but I'm fairly certain that as long as the current has not exceeded a certain threshold (such that the gel and buffer heat up to the point of causing the gel to contract or distort) resolution is function of migration distance.

Comment: I've used Lithium Borate with an agarose gel and high voltages (>200). Didn't turn out as well as advertised the few times I tried it though - worse than TAE.  If I had to try it again I would definitely lower the voltage.

Comment: sure.. try it once... and run any marker, along with running the same marker with TBE if possible, if you can to check for possibilities...

Comment: As you don't have sufficient reputation to post comments everywhere yet, I have converted this for you as it is more a comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: Someone appears to have used sodium borate for denaturing acrylamide gels, with no issues: http://www.protocol-online.org/biology-forums/posts/17703.html (no detail on the exact conditions, though).

Comment: A neighbouring lab uses the sodium borate buffer for genotyping in agarose gels. They can run the gels at 10% higher voltages than what I push my TAE buffer at (95V; 20 mA max). Is there a particular reason to use denaturing poly-acrylamide or to run them super fast?

Answer (score 1):

You can try SB (sodium boric acid), LA (lithum acetate) or LB (lithium boric acid) buffers. Thex generate must less heat then TAE or TBE buffers and can be run on much higher voltages and are much cheaper than TAE or TBE. Also they do not interfere with standard applications such as band excision and they last longer.

For more info try this sites:

http://www.fasterbettermedia.com/products.html
http://ddgehelp.blogspot.com/2008/01/alternative-electrophoresis-buffer-to.html